# How to change styles correctly MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sztsh.png)

I want to add style here background

```
MuiAccordion: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      position: 'inherit',
      '& .Mui-expanded': {
        background: 'rgba(196, 199, 208, 0.2)',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

But I have added in another place

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqrTi.png)

please tell me what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the space in '& .Mui-expanded', so this will become to '&.Mui-expanded'

```js
MuiAccordion: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      position: 'inherit',
      '&.Mui-expanded': {
        background: 'rgba(196, 199, 208, 0.2)',
      },
    },
  },
},
```